# A global login (many sites)

Tags: php, database

We are a growing network but we figured we want to keep that the User only would need one account in order to access the network different sites. (Similar to Stackoverflow's login, If you login in to another "site" you use your account credentials and than your account is created). We want our own login system (Username, password) and not OpenId, as we'd probably have that in the future, but the main focus right now is the global login.

How can  I do this? Do a Curl request and send back a cookie? Have a "database" just for the login procedure and on first login also create a new "User" in the site specified database?

Suggestions?.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/

Comment: First you should check how OpenID is done

Answer (score 1):

This is done on stackexchange sites as well using **[OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)**, check out this post:

- [Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)

Comment: *We want our own login system (Username, password) and not **OpenId***

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It's unrelated.